# Views Table Grouping not working if group field is blank

Tags: views, entities

I'm using Drupal 7. In a field collection view, I have data in a table that has field groups. I have 3 fields I want to group on, the first two are required, the third is optional. Everything worked until I added the 3rd field. When there are records with no data in that field, the record shows up as a row of empty table cells. Can anyone suggest a fix for this?

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a way to conditionally control this. For example, can you turn grouping off if a certain field has a certain value? Or, if a field has no value?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. If the field I was grouping by was empty in all the nodes under another grouping, no results would show. In my case it was State->Administrative Area, and if none of the nodes in the state had administrative areas no results would show under the state.

The solution that ended up working for me was to uncheck the 'Hide rewriting if empty' box in the Configure field: Content: Administrative Area->No Results Behavior section. 'Hide if empty' was already unchecked so I didn't fool about with it.

Answer (score 0):

On the edit screen for your view:

- Under 'Fields', click on the third grouping field.
- Then click 'No results behavior'.
- Check the box labeled 'Hide if empty'.
- Click apply, and then save your view.